# How to pass value by a variable in this javascript query?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a html page where user can submit a input value and get sorted data by input value. Each user can submit different value and get data form google sheet.

I tried sheetrock.js but cant solve this problem.

```js
var mySpreadsheet = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qT1LyvoAcb0HTsi2rHBltBVpUBumAUzT__rhMvrz5Rk/edit#gid=0'
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#switch-hitters').sheetrock({
        url: mySpreadsheet,
        query: "select A,C,D,E,L where A = 'PHI' order by L asc",
        fetchSize: 10
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sheetrock/1.1.4/dist/sheetrock.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<table id="switch-hitters" class="table table-condensed table-striped"></table>
```

I need user can change vale of A= 'PHI' form a html input box

Comment: Could you post any errors you're having specifically? 
You mention wanting an HTML <form> field that will determine your sheetrock query but don't have one in your code yet?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the string of the query to

```
`select A,C,D,E,L where A = '${phi}' order by L asc`
```

and then add an input in your document:

```
<form name="form">
  phi: <input type="text"/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and after that add this script:

```
$("form").on('submit', function (e) {
   phi = $("input:first").val();
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

dont forget to declare `phi` at the start of your script by `let phi = '';`
just after declaring `mySpreasheet` variable